# How to fix the failed gtk modules when launching a snap?

Tags: gtk, snap

When launching many snaps, I see the following messages in the terminal:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar" 
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail" 
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge" 
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

How can I fix the loading of those modules?

The specific snap I'm looking at right now is keepassx-elopio. To install and launch it:

```
$ sudo snap install keepassx-elopio
$ keepassx-elopio.keepassx
```

Here is the snapcraft.yaml: https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/blob/master/keepassx/snapcraft.yaml

Comment: AFAIK, they are optional plugins for GTK theme engine. You may include them in snap package or configure Qt to ignore gtk theme.